# Twig strip textarea and create array

Tags: twig

I'm trying to strip some text from a value and afterwards create an array from it with the stripped values.
I'm having troubles to strip the text value.

I can only do this on the frontend since I have no access to the backend (SaaS platform)

In below example `value.value` (originally a textarea) returns the following text:

```
[185047078]1x something - Type 1
[415533322]1x something - something
[152890667]1x something 500x500 mm
```

I want to strip the text so I have `[185047078]`, `[415533322]`, `[152890667]` left or without the brackets.

Normally in JS you would do something like:

```
hide_ids = txt.match(/[^\]\[]+(?=\])/g)
```

However it need to be done in Twig.

Afterwards I want to push the values into an array `hide_ids`.

```
 {% set hide_ids = [] %}
 {% if product.custom %}
   {% for custom in product.custom %}
     {% if 'Some title' in custom.title %}
       {% for value in custom.values %}

         {% set hide_this_id = value.value %}
         {% if hide_this_id matches '{/[^\]\[]+(?=\])/g}' %}
             {% set hide_ids = hide_ids | merge([hide_this_id]) %}
          {% endif %}


        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

  {% set hidden = false %}

  {% if id in hide_ids %}
    {% set hidden = true %}     
  {% endif %}
```

What is the equivalent of `match` in Twig? I also tried `replace` but I just can't get that text stripped.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you only want to keep the id's?

Comment: @DarkBee: Yes indeed, or with the brackets. Anyway something that I can use to create an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with some simple string functions.

```
{% for id in ids %}
    {{ id | split(']', 2)[0] | replace({'[': '',}) }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/rq2ypg)

---

- [split](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) is the [explode](https://secure.php.net/explode) of `twig`. This will separate your string in chased based on the `]` character. The 2nd parameter (`2`) ensures there will only be maximum 2 parts in the array.
- [replace](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html) is just `str_replace`

---

If you wanted to solve this with regex you would either need to write a function/filter with `preg_match` or install an extension like [this](https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions#pcre)